# VSCode color settings: name of element that appears when document is scrolled?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a color theme, and I found an element without a setting.

There's a highlight under the tabs only when the document is *not* scrolled all the way to the top.

### At top of file

[image: at top of file]

In the first picture, the document is scrolled up, so the line is invisible.

### Scrolled

[image: scrolled]

Here I've scrolled down a few pixels, and you can see a horizontal line, lighter.

**I want to eliminate the horizontal highlight line in the second picture.**

What workbench color customization setting references it?

Or is there a setting to eliminate edge blur on scrolled pages?

--

EDIT: Inspecting via Dev Tools reveals that the CSS in question is the class `scroll-decoration`, which gets added whenever the document is not scrolled to the top.

The shadow can be eliminated by commenting out the box shadow, or setting the height to 0.

However, I'm still unsure how to get this behavior to persist short of a pull request.

```
.monaco-editor .scroll-decoration {
     box-shadow: #dddddd 0 6px 6px -6px inset; 
}
```

```
.monaco-editor .scroll-decoration {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 6px;
}
```

Comment: it is the same CSS shadow they have around the find box, they use the tab background color

Comment: @rioV8 Hmm, which specific tab setting is it?  I have all of the following colors set, with no effect: `tab.activeBackground, tab.inactiveBackground, tab.activeForeground, tab.inactiveForeground,`

Comment: maybe with the Help > Dev Tools you can find the div that has the shadow and what name-color it has

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, this is on the right track!  It's a div that acquires the class `scroll-decoration` when the document is not fully scrolled to the top.  However, I don't know how to use this information to affect its color in `settings`.  The `div` itself doesn't have an ID, and it doesn't appear in auto-complete suggestions.

Comment: what is the style of `scroll-decoration`

Comment: @rioV8 I edited the question to add new info based on your suggestions.  There isn't any `style` aside from width -- however, there *is* relevant CSS (added to question).

Comment: I think it is themeable because `High Contrast` does not have this `#ddd` shading.

Comment: @rioV8 I agree!  I just don't know where to find it.  It's not in the API: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color as far as I can tell.

Comment: have you looked at the source of **High Contrast**